# Generate new ID using R

Tags: r

As a R newbie I want to generate a new id variable based on an existing one:

```
df = read.table(text = 
              "id 
10
10
15
15
19 
34
 ", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

The new id should start from 1, like this:

```
df = read.table(text = 
              "id  new_id
            10  1
            10  1
            15  2
            15  2
            19  3
            34  4
            ", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `?factor` is your friend.  Please do a bit of searching around the internets before posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
transform(df, new_id=as.numeric(factor(id)))
```